# PHP cUrl Auto Login

Tags: php, curl, authentication, autologin

I need some help if is possible with a php curl auto login script.

I am working on a project and one of the problems is that i need to login to: http://www.marketbook.co.uk and scrap some infos, but only logged in.

Please if you can spare some minutes and take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong:

```
<?php

// options
$USER             = 'userrrrrrrr';
$PASSWORD         = 'passsssssss';
$cookie_file_path = "cookies.txt";
$LOGINURL         = "http://www.marketbook.co.uk/Homepage/Default.aspx"; 
$agent            = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";


// begin script
$ch = curl_init(); 

// extra headers
$headers[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
$headers[] = "Connection: Keep-Alive";
$headers[] = "Host: www.marketbook.co.uk";
$headers[] = "Content-Length: 246";
$headers[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$headers[] = "Origin: http://www.marketbook.co.uk";
$headers[] = "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
$headers[] = "Referer: http://www.marketbook.co.uk/homepage/default.aspx?";
$headers[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8";



// basic curl options for all requests
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,  0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path); 

// set first URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL);

// execute session to get cookies and required form inputs
$content = curl_exec($ch); 

// grab the hidden inputs from the form required to login
$fields = getFormFields($content);

$fields['__VIEWSTATE'] = $viewstate;
$fields['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = $viewstategen;
$fields['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $eventval;
$fields['txtUName'] = $USER;
$fields['txtUPass'] = $PASSWORD;

// set postfields using what we extracted from the form
$POSTFIELDS = http_build_query($fields); 

// change URL to login URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $LOGINURL); 

// set post options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POSTFIELDS); 

// perform login
$result = curl_exec($ch);  

print $result; 


function getFormFields($data)
{
    if (preg_match('/(<form action="op.*?<\/form>)/is', $data, $matches)) {
        $inputs = getInputs($matches[1]);

        return $inputs;
    } else {
        die('didnt find login form');
    }
}

function getInputs($form)
{
    $inputs = array();

    $elements = preg_match_all('/(<input[^>]+>)/is', $form, $matches);

    if ($elements > 0) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $elements; $i++) {
            $el = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $matches[1][$i]);

            if (preg_match('/name=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $name)) {
                $name  = $name[1];
                $value = '';

                if (preg_match('/value=(?:["\'])?([^"\'\s]*)/i', $el, $value)) {
                    $value = $value[1];
                }

                $inputs[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $inputs;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question what your problem is and you have a long piece of code for us to look through. What error messages are you getting? At what point does it not do what you expect it too? (try adding some debugging output)

Comment: the problem is that i can't make it login

Comment: All (except referrer maybe) of the items you specify in `$headers[]` should not be set manually. cURL handles and generates them for you. Especially this fixed size "Content-Length: 246" makes no sense. Remove all the extra headers and try again. Use the CURLOPT_REFERER option to set the referrer. See the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php